# Custom issue types in BitBucket issue tracker

Tags: bitbucket, issue-tracking

I recently starting using the issue tracker for my BitBucket repositories.  I've been able to move all of my open issues (just bugs and enhancements) over, but I noticed there's not an issue type like "question."  Is this something that I can add?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. The issue types in the built-in issue tracker are hardcoded and do not support adding custom ones at this time.

Comment: second that thought, very unfortunate.